# « Aliéner » pour traduire l'anglais « alienate »

Tags: usage, verbes

> Tous ces changements dans le journal ont aliéné ses lecteurs traditionnels.

Emploie-t-on couramment le verbe aliéner pour rendre l'idée de *alienate* (to cause someone or a group of people to stop supporting and agreeing with you) ?

Comment: Sans lire les définitions, je comprends ce verbe comme "rendre fou via une forme de répétition ou de harcèlement". Je pense que la plupart des gens l'associent à "l'aliénation par le travail", des ouvriers travaillant à la chaîne, répétant le même geste tels des robots, jusqu'à en perdre leur âme. Ceci dû au fait que le terme est très lié aux discours politiques. Je constate qu'il existe d'autres utilisations mais que celle que je donne existe effectivement, et je pense que c'est la définition qu'en donneraient beaucoup de gens, sans connaître l'existence d'une origine purement juridique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ton collègue a raison. On n'utiliserait pas *aliéner* ici.

Voici ce que je peux proposer :

> Tous les changements introduits dans le journal en ont éloigné les lecteurs traditionnels.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100439/discussion-between-jlliagre-and-folkvangr).

Answer (score 5):

Dans le Petit Robert, on trouve ce sens : « *s'aliéner les esprits, la sympathie de la population*, les perdre, les écarter de soi » mais le verbe « aliéner » me semble fortement lié à un état d'esprit négatif proche du chamboulement (aversion, rendre hostile, rendre fou...) ou irrémédiable (perdre, détacher...).

> Les lecteurs traditionnels se sont détournés du journal à la suite de tous ces changements.

La formulation ci-dessus me semble être une formulation courante.

Answer (score -1):

Oui, l'emploi est courant ; la définition suivante du [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ali%C3%A9ner) est celle qui couvre ce cas. (*caractères gras de user **LPH***)

> I. Emploi trans.
>   B. [L'obj. est une pers., une partie de la pers.]
>
> 2. [L'obj. est une pers. considérée dans ses rapports avec les choses ou avec autrui]
>      a) Aliéner **qqn (ou les facultés morales de qqn) à soi (de soi)**. Rendre moralement étranger à, détacher, détourner de, susciter l'hostilité. Aliéner les affections, les cœurs, les esprits (Ac. 1798-1932); Aliéner la bienveillance, la sympathie de
>
>    - La timidité nous concentre en nous-mêmes, et ressemble quelquefois à la fierté et au dédain : elle **nous** aliène **ceux** devant qui nous tremblons précisément parce que nous ambitionnons trop leurs suffrages.
>        MAINE DE BIRAN, Journal, 1817, p. 30.
>    - Rien ne doit aliéner de **moi** les autres **hommes**; je ne suis le rival d'aucun d'eux; je ne puis pas plus les envier que les haïr; je refuserais ce qui les passionne, je refuserais de triompher d'eux, et je ne veux pas même les surpasser en vertu.
>        É. DE SENANCOUR, Obermann, t. 1, 1840, p. 26.
>    - Elle fut fort intimidée de l'avoir pour voisin de table; et malheureusement, sa timidité se traduisit par ce flot de paroles, qui **lui** aliéna du premier coup les **sympathies** de Christophe.
>        R. ROLLAND, Jean-Christophe, L'Adolescent, 1905, p. 252.
>
> Rem.  2. Le compl. second. peut anciennement rester sous-entendu :
>
> - En se prononçant pour les quatre articles, il pouvait donner une légère satisfaction au roi, d'ailleurs si aliéné de **lui**; mais il aliénait certainement le **pape** qui, pour le moment, lui était assez favorable ainsi qu'à ses amis.
>     Ch.-A. SAINTE-BEUVE, Port-Royal, t. 5, 1859, p. 156.

On peut remarquer que les prépositions pour le complément second sont « à » et « de ».
Dans la phrase citée (Tous ces changements musicaux dans le journal ont aliéné ses lecteurs traditionnels.) le complément second est donc sous entendu (journal) ; ce verbe est souvent employé sans ce complément.

Il semble que le choix entre les deux prépositions soit libre. L'ngram suivant ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ali%C3%A9n%C3%A9+de%2C+ali%C3%A9n%C3%A9+%C3%A0&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cali%C3%A9n%C3%A9%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cali%C3%A9n%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cali%C3%A9n%C3%A9%20de%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cali%C3%A9n%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc1)) n'est donné qu'à titre indicatif comme dans de nombreux cas « à » et « de » n'introduisent pas un complément d'objet mais un complément circonstanciel (aliéné à vie, aliéné de telle sorte que …).

***de***

- qu'est l'être-aliéné de la nature
- également aliéné de son essence
- Gregor Samsa sera d'abord aliéné de son corps
- est un faux-semblant aliéné de la condition humaine
- le serviteur aliéné de l'économie
- Il est ainsi aliéné de lui-même

***à***

- qui m'aliène à quelques caractéristiques (je suis « français », « bourgeois », « inculte …
- dans le miroir, aliéné à un reflet, à un double de lui-même, sur le mode d'une psychose
- La productivité de cet homme aliéné à lui- même ne peut s'expliquer autrement
- et qui, en retour, nous aliène à eux

---

Comme l'usage spécifique considéré semble être assez  contesté, vu certaines réponses, j'ajoute quelques indications.
Des exemples spécifiques concernant le contexte « journal/lecteurs » ne sont pas faciles à trouver, mais le suivant est sans équivoque.

- Les journaux spécialisés risquent eux aussi de pâtir d'un cynisme grandissant et de s'aliéner leurs lecteurs.

Néanmoins, d'autres exemples montrent une analogie qui rend difficile de penser comment le verbe ne serait pas applicable au contexte « journal/lecteurs ».

- Au début, Gorbatchev a été apparemment assez astucieux pour [...] procéder prudemment et se gagner des appuis afin de ne pas s'aliéner les institutions en place ou susciter l'hostilité de la population.
- Nous courons sans doute le risque de nous aliéner davantage cet effectif critique si nous ne saisissons pas l'occasion, importante et très opportune, de réagir à l'information qui nous a été présentée. [*L'effectif critique est une partie de la force ouvrière.*]
- Politicien habile, Morales a cherché à apparaître plus combatif que ses
  [...] concurrents, tout en cherchant simultanément à ne pas s'aliéner de façon irréparable la bourgeoisie bolivienne ni les impérialistes.
- Elle doit aller de l'avant pour cesser d'aliéner dangereusement l'électorat.
- Je vais peut-être m'aliéner les éleveurs de NFO et de MCO, mais à mon avis des chats semblables aux sibériens ont sans doute
  [...] précédé toutes les autres races à poils mi-longs, non seulement les Norvégiens et les Maine-coons, mais aussi les Angoras Turcs et les Turcs de Van.

Dans tous les cas cités il est question d'un programme  (social, politique,…) ou d'une proposition s'adressant à un groupe et dans tous les cas le verbe signifie « s'attirer le désintéressement » (de ce groupe), « être rejeté » (par ce groupe). Cela me semble assez convaincant.